# Selecting data from structured data, but the elegant functional way

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Apparently, my ability to think functional withered over time. I have problems to select a sub-dataset from a dataset. I can solve the problem the hacky imperative style, but I believe, there is a sweet functional solution, which I am unfortunately not able to find.

Consider this data structure (tried to not simplify it beyond usability):

```
class C
    attr_reader :attrC
    def initialize(base)
        @attrC = { "c1" => base+10 , "c2" => base+20, "c3" => base+30}
    end
end

class B
    attr_reader :attrB
    @@counter = 0
    def initialize
        @attrB = Hash.new
        @attrB["b#{@@counter}"] = C.new(@@counter)
        @@counter += 1
    end
end

class A
    attr_reader :attrA
    def initialize
        @attrA = { "a1" => B.new, "a2" => B.new, "a3" => B.new}
    end
end
```

which is created as `a = A.new`. The complete data set then would be

```
#<A: @attrA={"a1"=>#<B: @attrB={"b0"=>#<C: @attrC={"c1"=>10, "c2"=>20, "c3"=>30}>}>, 
             "a2"=>#<B: @attrB={"b1"=>#<C: @attrC={"c1"=>11, "c2"=>21, "c3"=>31}>}>, 
             "a3"=>#<B: @attrB={"b2"=>#<C: @attrC={"c1"=>12, "c2"=>22, "c3"=>32}>}>}>
```

which is subject to a selection. I want to retrieve only those instances of `B` where `attrB`'s key is `"b2"`.

My hacky way would is:

```
result = Array.new
A.new.attrA.each do |_,va|
    result << va.attrB.select { |kb,_| kb == "b2" }
end

p result.reject { |a| a.empty?} [0]
```

which results in exactly what I intended:

```
{"b2"=>#<C: @attrC={"c1"=>12, "c2"=>22, "c3"=>32}>}
```

but I believe there would be a one-liner using map, fold, zip and reduce.

Comment: This is a really inelegant data structure from a Ruby perspective. Why not just an array, or a Hash with numerical keys? The real problem with class variables like that is they're not thread safe, and in general are an ugly mess to get right. There's a lot going on here in all sorts of unusual directions which suggests this might be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What's the ultimate goal here?

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your remark concerning the data structures. I agree that the structure is rather unhandy. The data structure reflects a home automation central's data model. I use an API to retrieve a rather large XML tree and decided to create my model to be as equivalent as possible to not reduce my mental stability. `A` represents a device, `B` a channel, `C` a data point's state. Every class has further attributes and states. I fear, if I start to simplify the model, I will decrease the ability to improve the functional aspect of my software.

Comment: @tadman: I beg you pardon, but I didn't get your capital letters remark. `A`, `B` and `C` are class names with capital starting letter (well...), attributes start lowercase. Browsing through other code for some inspiration, I would guess `attribA` should be better be named `attrib_a`?

Comment: No need to put "(Ruby)" at the end of your question title; that's what tags are for.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have capital letters, at all, in variable or method names. Although keys can have them, it's inconsistent (e.g. `ID: id, Key: key`), though very old parts of Ruby (e.g. Net::HTTP) do use that. Prefer `attr_a` to `attrA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner:

```rb
a.attrA.values.select { |b| b.attrB.keys == %w(b2) }
```

This returns instances of `B`. In your question, you're getting `attrB` values rather than instances of `B`. If that's what you want, there's this ugly `reduce`:

```rb
a.attrA.values.reduce([]) { |memo, b| memo << b.attrB if b.attrB.keys == %w(b2) ; memo }
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, though?